# How Serialize nested class with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

I need get breadType property from Sandwich class. I have 2 clases both serializable:

```
@Serializable
class MyFood {
    var name: String? = null
    var price: Int? = null
    var sand: Sandwich? = null
}

@Serializable
class Sandwich{
    var breadType: String? = null
}
```

And this JSON:

```
"MyFood": {
    "name": "Sandwich double",
    "price": 100.00,
    "breadType": 100.00
 }
```

I get JsonUnknownKeyException exception:

```
"Strict JSON encountered unknown key: breadType\nYou can disable strict mode to skip unknown keys"
```

What I do wrong please!?

Comment: There is no "sand" key in your JSON. Do you want to convert the JSON into objects?

Comment: I want convert it to MyFood object. I need ignore "sand" and get all properties of Sandwich as they were of MyFood

Comment: You need to change your `MyFood` object. Is it allowed to do that?

Comment: No, I cant modify MyFood Object :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Retrofit:

Use JsonConfiguration(**strictMode = false)** on retrofit converter factory.

```
// your retrofit builder
.addConverterFactory(
    Json(
        JsonConfiguration(strictMode = false)
    ).asConverterFactory(MediaType.get("application/json"))
)
```

In other words,You should use `Json.nonstrict.parse()` instead of `Json.parse()`

Or we can pass in constructor:

```
serializer = KotlinxSerializer(Json.nonstrict)
```

Edited:

As per your json your class should be like this:

```
Serializable
class MyFood {
    var name: String? = null
    var price: Int? = null
    var breadType: double? = null
}
```

This will work but if you want to use Sandwich class then your json should be like this:

```
"MyFood": { 
    "name": "Sandwich double",
    "price": 100.00, 
    "sand": {
        "breadType":100.00
    }
}
```

Comment: I need get all properties of Sandwich as they were of MyFood

Comment: I hope you got it what's the issue

Comment: Thanks. I can modify json or MyFood class :(